# WPF - How do I get the value from the parent element?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, styles, controltemplate

Hi i am trying to pass from Button Content to ControlTemplate -> Label Content
How can i do this?

I am just starting to learn xaml and faced such a problem, I would be very grateful for any help.

Code:

````
    <Style x:Key="CloseBtn" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="Flex"/> <!---From here --->
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Label Name="Border" Focusable="False" Background="#00ff0000" Foreground="#A770FA" 
    Content="" <--- Over here --->
     VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
                    
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Use relative source in your binding to bind to properties on a parent control, in this case, it could be either :

```
<Label Name="Border" Focusable="False" Background="#00ff0000" Foreground="#A770FA" 
    Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}},Path=Content}"
     VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>

OR

<Label Name="Border" Focusable="False" Background="#00ff0000" Foreground="#A770FA" 
    Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},Path=Content}"
     VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
```

Relative source also allows you to bind to properties on the same control , ancestors upto a certain level, etc. Please refer to the documentation : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.relativesource?view=net-5.0